# Adding a table to a web map made in Folium

Tags: html, pandas, folium

I have made a nice Folium map however, the amount of data is small, but increasing. Right now it is grabbing a wildfire perimeter GeoJSON from NIFC and then getting points from my organization and doing a spatial join for the points within the fire perimeter. Then I filter the joined points from the original list and displaying one as a normal points layer and the other as a MarkerCluster because there are thousands of points.

It would be great to display a table of the spatially joined points and polygons in two separate tables on the side or bottom of the map. It doesn't necessarily need to be interactive (although that would be cool), I think a static HTML table would work fine for now. My googling has lead me to the to_html from the Pandas library that I'm already using with Folium. I haven't found any examples or ways to inject/pass that HTML into the HTML file for the map when Folium generates it.

Should I try and manipulate the HTML file separately after Folium generates it?